# What is a good online development IDE?

Tags: node.js, ide, development-environment

I want a good development IDE for a node.js developer. I also want one that can be downloaded on a local machine.

Comment: This is too opinion-based.

Comment: I mean I want a good one

Comment: https://glitch.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go for [c9.io](http://www.c9.io) that's an online IDE, It works pretty well for any language , and you don't even need to install any software locally. Everything in cloud.

For Offline IDE , I would recommend Sublime, It is used by most of the great developers worldwide.
In sublime you have a great potential for shortcuts and you will be working really fast once you have control over it.
All the best :)

Comment: Yes, absolutely ! I do it in sublime. But you have to learn and setup few things, that is called customization of IDE, The best part of SBULIME is customization . You can make it all yours. :) here is a good blog https://medium.com/@mohitkumar_19866/setting-up-a-good-javascript-ide-sublime-text-3-for-javascript-69e37cd56759

Comment: are you comfortable with the editor I mean is it enough for it?

Comment: Also I'm currently taking an online bootcamp in web development and the instructor is using node.js on cloud9 and there are 2 problems: the first is that I don't always have no internet connection and the second is that I'm afraid that using sublime or VS code will cause me problems as I'm using a different IDE than the intructor

Comment: What I would suggest is that, choose any IDE and make it yours, do not change IDE based on the instructors interest.

Comment: I mean does it affect anything

Comment: Like I see strange folders in his IDE like node modules which I can't see

Comment: No It does not affect anything related to files. For you issue with node_modules directory, do check if you have opened the correct folder .

Comment: do you have any guide on how to setup up node.js properly because I have alot of errors doing so

Comment: like after downloadin the node.js installer and running it what should I do

Comment: I cud not help you this way, because there can be error of various types and the reason can be very simple or complex.I would suggest you to go with a tutorial, as i think u r starting to learn node.js

Comment: yes I just finished learning the java script and jquery part and successfully created the the quizzes in the course. But I stopped for 2 days because I'm struggling to setup my Dev environment and choosing an IDE and setting it up as there are no tutorials available in the course and even Youtube I can't find any instructions.

Comment: I understand, i can help you with that, connect with me on Facebook search for hi@apathak.com